# How to access devise token auth registration controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, token

I am using [Devise auth token](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem for authenticating some parts of my rails app. But when I try to create a new user with the registration path, it  is giving me the following error`{"errors":["Authorized users only."]}`.

Here is the rspec code that I am using for the test,

```
it 'creates a user using email/password combo' do
    post api_user_registration_path, { email: 'xxx', password: 'yyy',password_confirmation: 'yyy'}
    puts last_response.body
    expect(last_response.body).not_to have_content('error')
end
```

Additional info: the model name is 'User' and the routes looks like,

```
namespace :api do
  scope :v1 do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  end
end
```

I understand that the devise is expecting the user to be authenticated before accessing this path, but this being the user registration, it needs to be outside the   authentication. Can you suggest a solution for this? Is there any configuration that I am missing here?

Comment: do you have devise :registerable added in your User Model

Comment: yes. have these in my User model, 'devise  :lockable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,:omniauthable'

Comment: Did you inherit the `Api::UserRegistrationsController` from `Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: In `Api::UserRegistrationsController` you should use `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create`

Comment: ha.. that could be it.  Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: Can you post your solution? I'm unsure exactly how to implement this controller

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: '/auth'
    end
  end
```

This will create the following routes:

```
        new_api_v1_user_session GET    /api/v1/auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#new                                                                                                                                  
            api_v1_user_session POST   /api/v1/auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#create                                                                                                                               
    destroy_api_v1_user_session DELETE /api/v1/auth/sign_out(.:format)       devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy                                                                                                                              
           api_v1_user_password POST   /api/v1/auth/password(.:format)       devise_token_auth/passwords#create                                                                                                                              
       new_api_v1_user_password GET    /api/v1/auth/password/new(.:format)   devise_token_auth/passwords#new                                                                                                                                 
      edit_api_v1_user_password GET    /api/v1/auth/password/edit(.:format)  devise_token_auth/passwords#edit                                                                                                                                
                                PATCH  /api/v1/auth/password(.:format)       devise_token_auth/passwords#update                                                                                                                              
                                PUT    /api/v1/auth/password(.:format)       devise_token_auth/passwords#update                                                                                                                              
cancel_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/auth/cancel(.:format)         devise_token_auth/registrations#cancel                                                                                                                          
       api_v1_user_registration POST   /api/v1/auth(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#create                                                                                                                          
   new_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/auth/sign_up(.:format)        devise_token_auth/registrations#new                                                                                                                             
  edit_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/auth/edit(.:format)           devise_token_auth/registrations#edit                                                                                                                            
                                PATCH  /api/v1/auth(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#update                                                                                                                          
                                PUT    /api/v1/auth(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#update                                                                                                                          
                                DELETE /api/v1/auth(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#destroy                                                                                                                         
     api_v1_auth_validate_token GET    /api/v1/auth/validate_token(.:format) devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
```

Also create an controller in `app/controllers/api/v1/api_base_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::BaseApiController < ActionController::Base

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken

end
```

Also add to your file `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think I am doing pretty much the same thing. Except my api controller is not in a an api folder, like you have it in your code. That did not fix it. :(. I have all these routes created by devise auth token.

Comment: thanks for the edit. My issue seems to be a compatibility issue with devise. I will post an update when I could solve it completely.